# longs functiooon cloj

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to use the `longs` function, but it's not working:

```
(println (longs 1 2 3))
```

Any examples?

The description in the site is not very good, which is why I'm having problems
http://clojure.org/cheatsheet

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect, what do you get, and why don't you like it?

Answer (score 6):

You're question is woefully incomplete, but I'll take a stab at it anyway.

The documentation for `longs` says:

> Usage: (longs xs)

That means, it's expecting *one* argument (named `xs` in this example). You're passing it three arguments.

The documentation for `longs` continues thus:

> Casts to `long[]`

Casting means: It doesn't change xs, it simply checks that it is an array of primitive `long` and then make this information available to the compiler. Basically, wrapping an expression that produces a `long[]` in `(longs ...)` is a type hint for Clojure so that it doesn't have to use reflection at runtime to resolve a method call using that value as an argument:

```
// Suppose we have a java class
class JavaClass {
    static long[] getSomeLongs() { ... }
    static long sum(long[] numbers) { ... }
    static float sum(float[] numbers) { ... }
}

;; And this Clojure code:

(defn numbers [] (JavaClass/getSomeLongs))
(JavaClass/sum (numbers))
```

Clojure is dynamically typed, so when it compiles the second line, it won't know that (numbers) returns an array of long. It will have to wait until run time and then look up the correct JavaClass/sum method using reflection. This is expensive.

The solution is to give the Clojure compiler a hint about the type of (numbers). That way it can choose the correct method to call at compile time, resulting in a faster running program:

```
(JavaClass/sum (longs (numbers)))
```

But, judging from your woefully incomplete question, that's probably not what you were expecting when you reached for `longs`. It seems you were hoping it would *create* an array of longs from the arguments you gave it. If that's what you want then use this:

```
(into-array Long/TYPE [1 2 3])
```

But, you're likely to be disappointed by the results of printing it:

```
user=> (println (into-array Long/TYPE [1 2 3]))
#<long[] [J@2321b59a>
```

That's what Java gives back when you ask it to convert an array into a String, so that's what Clojure prints. If you want to see the contents of the array printed back, you need to make a sequence:

```
user=> (println (seq (into-array Long/TYPE [1 2 3])))
(1 2 3)
```